# TrimExcess on a List on a ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using ScriptableObjects to store a List of Objects. This list of Objects in the code I keep track of the Count size of it. When I remove an item from the List I want to TrimExcess() it but it doesn't seem to be working for scriptableobjects.

```
x.Remove(q);
x.TrimExcess();
```

When I run it the first time the list is still the same size but the count is dropped which I can work with. However, when I stop and re-run unity, the count goes back up to where it was (For testing purposes I have 5 Objects and I am deleting one in code so dropping to 4) I know that trimexcess requires 10% empty before it works but on these small numbers, it should work.

Plus is there something else I can use that will always trim excess the list no matter what? The count size of the list is extremely important so I can't have it off at all.

Comment: Are you talking about `Count` or `Capacity`?

Comment: The **Count** of the list is a simple value and is never off ... It sounds like you actually mean the **Capacity** ... but without your code it is absolutely unclear why you would even care about it at all ...

Comment: The count is never off however because I am working with scriptable objects once I remove it, it says missing objects (Which is ignored in count) but once I restart it the scriptable object is a size of 5 even though only 4 elements are added. The 5th element says none and is getting included in the count. Regardless I got it to work with the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use an array

If memory is important you could use an array of a fixed size. That way you
will never have more memory used that what you need/want.

#List

In your question you talk about `Count`, not `Capacity`, but the question seem to be about list's capacity.

Are you aware that when you change capacity data is copied?

You can see this for yourself in the sources [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,9808f1f5ef16c436,references):

```
public int Capacity
{
    get => _items.Length;
    set
    {
        if (value < _size)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
        }

        if (value != _items.Length)
        {
            if (value > 0)
            {
                T[] newItems = new T[value];
                if (_size > 0)
                {
                    Array.Copy(_items, newItems, _size);
                }
                _items = newItems;
            }
            else
            {
                _items = s_emptyArray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### "always trim excess"

> Plus is there something else I can use that will always trim excess the list no matter what? The count size of the list is extremely important so I can't have it off at all

You can set the capacity to the size of the list directly with `l.Capacity = l.Count;`;

```
var l = Enumerable.Range(0,20).ToList();
Console.WriteLine($"After creation: size={l.Count}, capcity={l.Capacity}");

l.Remove(7);
Console.WriteLine($"After Remove: size={l.Count}, capcity={l.Capacity}");

l.TrimExcess();
Console.WriteLine($"After TrimExcess: size={l.Count}, capcity={l.Capacity}");

l.Capacity = l.Count;
Console.WriteLine($"After set Capacity: size={l.Count}, capcity={l.Capacity}");
```

Result:

```
After creation: size=20, capcity=20
After Remove: size=19, capcity=20
After TrimExcess: size=19, capcity=20
After set Capacity: size=19, capcity=19
```